# My Node.js gets an Route.post() got a object Undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I did a simple modularization through Node.js.

And I tried to do an api test through Postman, but my nodemon says that the following error occurred.

**error**

```
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.
```

**routes/router.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();
const user = require('../controller/user');

route.route('/user')
    .post(user.createUser)
    .get(user.readUser)
    .put(user.updateUser)
    .delete(user.deleteUser)

module.exports = route;
```

**controller/user.js**

```
exports.createUser = function (req, res) {
    res.send('user create.')
}

exports.readUser = function (req, res) {
    res.send('user read.')
}

exports.updateUser = function (req, res) {
    res.send('user update.')
}

exports.deleteUser = function (req, res) {
    res.send('user delete.')
}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const router = require('./routes/router');

app.use(router);

app.listen(port, err => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    else console.log('server on');
});
```

What's wrong with me?

Comment: Is that all that `controller/user.js` contains? It sounds like there's a circular dependency somewhere, but the code you post isn't showing one.

Comment: Your code is working for me in Node 10.11.0

Comment: Which code needs 10 versions? I have confirmed that using module.exports in the controller's user.js works. Is there a difference between using exports and module.exports?

Comment: None of this code has a specific requirement for Node 10, that's just what I had enabled in nvm at the moment. It should work probably all the way back to Node 4 if not earlier. Here's a good article on exports: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-module-exports-vs-exports-ec7e254d63ac

Comment: Yes, there is a difference, but I don't see how changing to `module.exports` would solve the problem _with the code as posted in your question_.

Comment: Ok. thanks Brandon

Comment: @robertklep Exactly. It should "just work". Works for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest transforming your current code (***controller/user.js***) to:

```
module.exports = {

createUser: function(req, res){
    res.send('User created')
},
readUser: function (req, res) {
    res.send('Viewing user.')
},
updateUser: function (req, res) {
    res.send('User updated.')
},
deleteUser: function (req, res) {
    res.send('User deleted.')
}}
```